# How can I get childnode's attribute from xml in java dom4j?

Tags: java, xml, attributes, dom4j, child-nodes

I'm trying to get the childnode's attribute from my xml file.For example,the file's name is `bb.xml`,
The xml is just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aaa>
 <bbb name="MainMenu">
  <ccc name="abc" Classes="1"
           A="2"
           B="3"/>
 </bbb>
 <bbb name="Mainwindow">
  <ccc name="abc" Classes="4"
           A="3"
           B="2"/>
 </bbb>
</aaa>
```

and main java file is this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   

    Document doc = new SAXReader().read(new File("D:/bb.xml"));
    List itemList = doc.selectNodes("/aaa");
    for (Iterator iter=itemList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Element el = (Element)iter.next();

    String name = el.attributeValue("name");
    System.out.println("name:"+name);
    String b = el.attributeValue("B");
    System.out.println("b:"+b); 
    }
```

I get the result in my console:

```
name:null
b:null
```

But  I want the result is:

```
name:MainMenu
b:3
name:Mainwindow
b:2
```

How can figure it out?

Comment: Try `e1.getAttribute("name").getValue()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
    Document doc = new SAXReader().read(new File("D:/bb.xml"));
    Element root = doc.getRootElement();
    Iterator bbbIt = root.elementIterator();
    while (bbbIt.hasNext()) {
        Element bbb = ((Element) bbbIt.next());
        System.out.println("name:" + bbb.attributeValue("name"));
        Iterator cccIt = bbb.elementIterator();
        while (cccIt.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("b:"
                    + ((Element) cccIt.next()).attributeValue("B"));
        }
    }

}
```

A better solution (because of flexibility) is to use Java native `org.w3c.dom` package. That way the solution would look like this:

```
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        org.w3c.dom.Document myDoc = db.parse(new File("D:/bb.xml"));
        org.w3c.dom.NodeList bbbNodes = myDoc.getElementsByTagName("bbb");
        for (int i=0; i < bbbNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            if (bbbNodes.item(i).hasAttributes())
                System.out.println(bbbNodes.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name"));
            org.w3c.dom.NodeList cccNodes = bbbNodes.item(i).getChildNodes();
            for (int j=0; j < cccNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                if (cccNodes.item(j).hasAttributes())
                    System.out.println(cccNodes.item(j).getAttributes().getNamedItem("B"));
            }
        }
```

In any case: don't forget the closing `</aaa>` in your xml.

Comment: Thank u very much for solving my problem and the reminding,I have Added the </aaa>. :)

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was helpful, please mark and/or accept the answer by clicking on the symbol.